# Formatting of jQuery (and javascript) code blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery

After my nth mistake related to misplaced curly brackets and parentheses, is it only me that really wants to write javascript and jQuery in the following structure? Is there an IDE that will auto-collapse it back down to the more compact structure once I've done making sure the code works?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
  $("#tour").on("click", "button", function()
  { 
    $(".photos").slideToggle();
  });


  $(".photos").on("mouseenter", "li", function()
  {
    $(this).find("span").slideToggle();
  });


  $(".photos").on("mouseleave", "li", function()
  {
    $(this).find("span").slideToggle();
  });

});
```

P.S. I've seen the video where Douglas Crockford explains why not to write blocks this way. That's why I was hoping there was an IDE that would fix it up for me afterwards.

Comment: Write more code, seriously, that's how you stop making syntax errors. That and a good text-editor with support for [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/). I write complete blocks first so you never forget to close them, so you start with `function(){}`, then `function(a,b){}`, then `function(a,b){...}`, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are many text editor, which has the feature of collapse.  Among them that I have used so far

> **1. Notepad++**  [image]
>
> **2. Visual Studio 2012**, is more powerful.  This will show error if any braces or syntax you miss
>
> **3. Sublime text 2** [image]
>
> I also remember **Aptana studio** has these features for JS(mainly for Javascript/jQuery).

However, when starting writing function complete placing the braces first.

```
function method1 () {
};
```

This is my way of handling the syntax.